# $3$ digits numbers in which digits are repeated.

Tags: combinatorics

> Total number of $3$ digit number which can be formed by using the digits $1,2,3,4,3,2,1$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Total no. of $3$ digits numbers in which exactly $2$ digits are identical, are

$112,113,114,221,223,224,331,332,334$

So Total numbers of $3$ digits numbers are $\displaystyle \frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}+\frac{3!}{2!}$

So we get sum $ = 27$

And Total no. of $3$ digits numbers in which all digits are distinct,are

$123,124,234,341$

So Total numbers of $3$ digits numbers are $\displaystyle3!+3!+3!+3!=24$

So we get Total $ = 27+24=51.$

Is my solution is right, If not Then how can I calculate It, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but tedious and runs the danger of missing something due to carelessness.

You could have worded it instead as breaking it into cases.

- case1: a repeated number
- case 2: no repeated numbers

In each case, approach via multiplication principle.

Counting case 1: pick which number repeated, pick nonrepeated, pick location of nonrepeated: $3\cdot 3\cdot 3=27$.

Counting case 2: pick number in slot one, in slot two, in slot three: $4\cdot 3\cdot 2=24$.

This gives, as you already found, $27+24=51$ total arrangements.

Comment: I am confused, in repeated ways, why 3x3x3? There are 1,2,3,4

Comment: @lifeforbetter because we only had one 4 available it is impossible when selecting the digit that will repeat that if will be the 4.

Comment: So we eliminate 4? Only 123 ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Step 1:  Pick which one of $\{1,2,3\}$ was repeated (*noting that $4$ could not have been repeated since there was only one $4$ available*).  Step 2: pick which of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ the remaining number was noting that it cannot be what was picked in step 1 which reduces the number of options here down to only three options.  Step 3: Pick which slot was occupied by the singleton number.

Comment: Ok. 123 at first option, cuz they can be repeated, then left 1234 minus the number i picked, if i picked 2  left 134 , means left 3 combinations and the next step is 3 slots means 122 can be 221 can be 212 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct.  In the second case, you want to find the number of 3 digit numbers with distinct digits where the digits are taken from $\{1,2,3,4\}$. This number is just $P(4,3)=4 \times 3 \times 2 = 24$ because the first digit can be chosen in 4 ways, the second in 3 ways (since the second digit can be any digit except the first digit), and the third digit can be chosen in 2 ways (since it can be any of the four digits available except the two digits chosen for the first and second positions).